# Asterisk cdr mysql query performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem that I'm not able to understand..
I have two queries (the database is MySQL, with only one table with all the cdr data):

```
SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE userfield LIKE 'audio:%' 
  AND (calldate >= '2016-10-26 00:00:00' 
  AND calldate <= '2016-10-26 23:59:59') 
  AND duration > 8 
ORDER BY uniqueid DESC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0;
```

which runs in 0.05 secs and another one:

```
SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE userfield LIKE 'audio:%' 
  AND (calldate >= '2016-10-26 15:00:00' 
  AND calldate <= '2016-10-26 16:00:00') 
  AND duration > 8 
ORDER BY uniqueid DESC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0;
```

which runs in 39.12 secs!! (note that the only difference are in the calldate fields)

I'm really not know much about performance in MySQL so I don't know where to start, maybe an index issue?

Comment: Thanks, EXPLAIN is a good start, but in this case is only one table, so I can´t play much with the execution plan.

Comment: I haven´t used EXPLAIN that much before, but for what I see in this case, there is only one row and the possible_keys and keys field match my current index (the one over the calldate column) so I don´t know really what to do (although there is a field I don´t get that is the Extra field, which says "Using where; Using filesort" )

Comment: "Using filesort" mean you have no space in memory for your temporary tables. You have increase bufferspace for sort(depend of your table engine types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create index for calldate field(or do "show index from cdr" to see if you already have one

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html

2) Create query which use index.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I did have an index created, but the index hint that you pointed out in the second link did the trick!